Why is the performance of these two equal queries so different?
This specific query has an average return time of 3:40 minutes
SELECT ROUND((SUM(ENF.TEMPO) / 24 / 60), 2) AS BROCHADEIRA
FROM (
    SELECT
    SZ9030.Z9_RECURSO AS COD_REC, ((ISNULL(TEMPO.TEMP, 0) + ISNULL(STP.TEMP, 0)) * SC2030.C2_QUANT) AS TEMPO
    FROM SZ9030
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Z9_OP, MAX(R_E_C_N_O_) AS ULT_BIP
        FROM SZ9030
        WHERE Z9_OP IN (
            SELECT CONCAT(SC2030.C2_NUM, '01001')
            FROM SC2030
            WHERE C2_DATRF = '' AND D_E_L_E_T_  = '')
        GROUP BY Z9_OP)
    AS ULTI_BIP ON SZ9030.Z9_OP = ULTI_BIP.Z9_OP AND R_E_C_N_O_  = ULTI_BIP.ULT_BIP
    INNER JOIN SC2030 ON LEFT(SZ9030.Z9_OP, 6) = SC2030.C2_NUM
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SG2030.G2_RECURSO, SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SUM(ROUND(((ABS(FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) - SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 100) + (FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 60)) / NULLIF(SG2030.G2_LOTEPAD, 0), 2)) AS TEMP 
        FROM SG2030
        WHERE D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND G2_RECURSO = '02910'
        GROUP BY SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SG2030.G2_RECURSO
    ) AS TEMPO ON (CASE
        WHEN TEMPO.G2_PRODUTO LIKE '%P' THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO), 'P')
        ELSE RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO)
    END) = RTRIM(TEMPO.G2_PRODUTO)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SG2030.G2_RECURSO, SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SUM(ROUND((((ABS(FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) - SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 100) + (FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 60)) / NULLIF(SG2030.G2_LOTEPAD, 0)), 2)) AS TEMP 
        FROM SG2030
        WHERE G2_RECURSO = '02911' AND SG2030.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
        GROUP BY SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SG2030.G2_RECURSO
    ) AS STP ON (CASE
        WHEN STP.G2_PRODUTO LIKE '%P' THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO), 'P')
        ELSE RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO)
    END) = RTRIM(STP.G2_PRODUTO)
    WHERE SZ9030.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SC2030.D_E_L_E_T_  = '' AND SZ9030.Z9_RECURSO = '02910')
AS ENF;

This other one (which is the same but with different parameters) returned the data in less than a second
SELECT ROUND((SUM(ENF.TEMPO) / 24 / 60), 2) AS FRESA
FROM (
    SELECT
    SZ9030.Z9_RECURSO AS COD_REC, ((ISNULL(TEMPO.TEMP, 0) + ISNULL(STP.TEMP, 0)) * SC2030.C2_QUANT) AS TEMPO
    FROM SZ9030
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Z9_OP, MAX(R_E_C_N_O_) AS ULT_BIP
        FROM SZ9030
        WHERE Z9_OP IN (
            SELECT CONCAT(SC2030.C2_NUM, '01001')
            FROM SC2030
            WHERE C2_DATRF = '' AND D_E_L_E_T_  = '')
        GROUP BY Z9_OP)
    AS ULTI_BIP ON SZ9030.Z9_OP = ULTI_BIP.Z9_OP AND R_E_C_N_O_  = ULTI_BIP.ULT_BIP
    INNER JOIN SC2030 ON LEFT(SZ9030.Z9_OP, 6) = SC2030.C2_NUM
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SG2030.G2_RECURSO, SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SUM(ROUND(((ABS(FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) - SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 100) + (FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 60)) / NULLIF(SG2030.G2_LOTEPAD, 0), 2)) AS TEMP 
        FROM SG2030
        WHERE D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND G2_RECURSO = '00610'
        GROUP BY SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SG2030.G2_RECURSO
    ) AS TEMPO ON (CASE
        WHEN TEMPO.G2_PRODUTO LIKE '%P' THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO), 'P')
        ELSE RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO)
    END) = RTRIM(TEMPO.G2_PRODUTO)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SG2030.G2_RECURSO, SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SUM(ROUND((((ABS(FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) - SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 100) + (FLOOR(SG2030.G2_TEMPAD) * 60)) / NULLIF(SG2030.G2_LOTEPAD, 0)), 2)) AS TEMP 
        FROM SG2030
        WHERE G2_RECURSO = '00611' AND SG2030.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''
        GROUP BY SG2030.G2_PRODUTO, SG2030.G2_RECURSO
    ) AS STP ON (CASE
        WHEN STP.G2_PRODUTO LIKE '%P' THEN CONCAT(RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO), 'P')
        ELSE RTRIM(SC2030.C2_PRODUTO)
    END) = RTRIM(STP.G2_PRODUTO)
    WHERE SZ9030.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' AND SC2030.D_E_L_E_T_  = '' AND SZ9030.Z9_RECURSO = '00610')
AS ENF;

At first I assumed the huge difference would simply be the amount of records with the matching value of '02910' or '02911', but it is not. The '00610' or '00611' value has 3x more records than '0291X', in fact, it probably is of all others the value with the less records, but every other SG2030.G2_RECURSO value returns way more records in 2-5 seconds.
Unhappily, this database I am working on is in production and I do not have the access to show any execution plans or to change any table structure, I can only do a better query with what I get. That's why the column names and other stuffs are in a "bad shape".

Would need to see the execution plans via Paste The Plan.

Without concrete execution plans, it is impossible to make any concrete claims. The main difference between the two queries seems that you are filtering RECURSO for different values.
Two of possible reasons:

If one value has significantly more records than the other one, the SQL engine must process significantly more rows, and that takes time.

If SQL engine THINKS one values has significantly more records, it might come up with execution plan, that would work well for a record with a lot of rows (e.g. building temporary index), but is wasteful for your particular case.


Possible solution to both 1. & 2. would be refreshing/creating statistics, so that they better represent actual content of your table, and allow the SQL engine to make better fitting execution plan.
You can refresh statistics like this:
UPDATE STATISTICS MyTable;

Or maybe
UPDATE STATISTICS MyTable WITH FULLSCAN;

However, beware! The FULLSCAN option will scan the full table - this will give you more accurate statistics, but it also requires more resources. You might not want to run that on production system outside of maintenance window.
But again, without actual execution plans, it's just stab in the dark.

Unhappily I do not have permission to do a execution plan, so I have to stick with a stab in the dark. Also the value I told about (02910, 02911) has way less records than any other G2_RECURSO value, so I am sticking with the second possible reason. How can I make the SQL stop thinking that the value has a lot of records?

I would suggest either asking for permission to view execution plans, or escalate the issue and let someone with necessary permissions to deal with it. Execution plans are basic tool for every query tuner, I can't imagine working without them.

(I have added the example of UPDATE STATISTICS command, but if you can't view execution plans, I doubt they have allowed you to do this either.)

It's possible that you always run the "longer-running" query first, at which point SQL Server caches some of the data, making subsequent queries run much faster.
This often happens in my work where the first query of a large table can take minutes, and after changing a filter, take seconds.
It would be interesting to see if the same occurs if you restart SQL Server and run the queries in the opposite order.

Unfortunately it is a production database and I do not have authorization to restart the SQL Server, but I do know that the queries with other values gave me the records in 2-5 seconds in their first executions.
